# OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING error with gdal_rasterize

Tags: gdal, gdal-rasterize, pbf

I've been trying to rasterize big PBF (1.2GB) file using gdal_rasterize and got this error:

```
ERROR 1: Too many features have accumulated in lines layer. Use the OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING=YES configuration option, or the INTERLEAVED_READING=YES open option, or the GDALDataset::GetNextFeature() / GDALDatasetGetNextFeature() API.
```

so I added  `--config OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING YES` to gdal_rasterize command and the error dissapeared, but in result I've got empty file, that is gdalinfo -stats reports

```
ERROR 1: test2.tif, band 1: Failed to compute statistics, no valid pixels found in sampling.
  NoData Value=200
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=0
```

As a walkaround I converted the PBF to GPKG file, but I'm wondering if there is a way to use gdal_rasterize with large PBFs without converting.

I use GDAL 3.5.0 on Linux (Centos7).

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when GDAL/OGR is reading the PBF data. There is some information about when using interleaved reading is needed at https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#interleaved-reading.

The error message is raised by the OSM driver after line https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/osm/ogrosmlayer.cpp#L324

and it is triggered when  `m_nFeatureArraySize > MAX_THRESHOLD`. The MAX_THRESHOLD is set into 100000 in the code at line https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/osm/ogrosmlayer.cpp#L62.

I do not know why gdal_rasterize creates an empty image with `--config OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING YES`. I guess that it should work but but maybe the gdal_rasterize application has not been updated to implement this:

> Starting with GDAL 2.2, applications should use the
> GDALDataset::GetNextFeature() API to iterate over features in the
> order they are produced.

If you wish you can write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask if you have found a bug and if confirmed, create a bug report at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/new.